# Excel white screen frozen

Tags: excel, freeze

My excel seems to freeze once in a while. I have 16GB RAM and two Intel Xeon 2.6GHz processors.

Is there anything I can do to avoid such instances? It really eats up a lot of my time and I lose some edits I may have made.[image]

Excel 2013, Windows 7 enterprise. Just copying 10,000 rows and 15 columns worth of data from one excel to another. The entire excel sheet has many formulae and pivots. The size of the files are less than 25MBs.

Comment: What's your version of Excel? What's your OS? What are you doing in the spreadsheet? Volatile formulas? External data sources?

Comment: Excel 2013, Windows 7 enterprise. Just copying 10,000 rows and 15 columns worth of data from one excel to another. The entire excel sheet has many formulae and pivots. The size of the files are less than 25MBs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are "just copying 10,000 rows and 15 columns", with many formulas and pivots, with a volume of "less than 25 MBs", that copy operation is probably creating an avalanche of re-calculation, as the pasted cells hit the other file and formulas need to be evaluated to accommodate the new data.

Even with a lot of RAM and fast processors, it's fairly easy to bring Excel down to a crawl.

You may want to re-consider alternatives to the copy/paste technique and you may want to inspect your formulas for efficiency/performance drains.

Without further detail about the exact nature of your files, I suggest you take a look at Charles Williams' tips for calculation speed and spreadsheet efficency at http://www.decisionmodels.com. He offers brilliant tools and techniques to help analyze calculation bottlenecks, with free code if you are willing to put in the work. If not, you can purchase his add-in and identify your spreadsheet performance bottlenecks immediately.